# Lucene.Net.Index.TermBuffer null reference exception

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I have a document collection that I search through using Lucene.net.
Works great.

When I try and enter new documents I get a null reference exception on the Termbuffer.It works fine when I just bulk insert to initialize the doc collection.

I get this error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at    Lucene.Net.Index.TermBuffer.Set(Term term) in           d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\Index\TermBuffer.cs:line 112
```

Here is some of the implementation:

```
    public FSDirectory Directory
    {
        get
        {
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(LuceneDir))
            {
                var filePath = new FileInfo(LuceneDir);
                filePath.Directory.Create();
            }

            if (DirectoryTemp == null) DirectoryTemp = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo(LuceneDir));
            if (IndexWriter.IsLocked(DirectoryTemp)) IndexWriter.Unlock(DirectoryTemp);
            var lockFilePath = Path.Combine(LuceneDir, "write.lock");
            if (File.Exists(lockFilePath)) File.Delete(lockFilePath);
            return DirectoryTemp;
        }
    }

var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, new HashSet<string>());
using (var writer = new IndexWriter(Directory, analyzer, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED))
{
    foreach (var sampleData in sampleDatas)     AddToLuceneIndex(sampleData, writer);
    //writer.Commit();
}


 public override void AddToLuceneIndex(T sampleData, IndexWriter writer)
    {
        try
        {
            writer.DeleteDocuments(boolQuery);

            var doc = new Document();
            doc.Add(new Field("MongoId", sampleData.Id, Field.Store.YES,        Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
            doc.Add(new Field("PackageId", sampleData.ProductId, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
            doc.Add(new Field("DosageFormname", sampleData.DosageFormname, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
            doc.Add(new Field("CompositeName", sampleData.CompositeName, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            doc.Add(new Field("ProprietaryName", sampleData.ProprietaryName, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            doc.Add(new Field("RouteName", sampleData.RouteName, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            doc.Add(new Field("SubstanceName", sampleData.SubstanceName, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            doc.Add(new Field("Strength", sampleData.Strength, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            doc.Add(new Field("Unit", string.Empty, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

            writer.AddDocument(doc);               

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("AD:AddToLuceneIndex(T, IndexWriter)::" + ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
        }
    }
```

It gets this error when the Indexwriter is getting rcycled right before the Using statement is finished.
Anyone have an idea of what might be happening? thanks!

Comment: I tried your suggestion. Unfortunately, it still results in the nullreference exception.

Comment: I don't see an obvious source of the exception you're seeing.  Perhaps you could simplify and provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?  I will say, your handling of the `FSDirectory` looks *extremely* sketchy.  Maybe try replacing that whole get block with `return new RAMDirectory()`, and see if you still run into issues.